# Advantage of using mx:Text over mx:Label

Tags: apache-flex, text, flex3

What is the advantage of using mx:Text over mx:Label in Flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Text control displays multiline, noneditable text. Use the Label
>   control if you need only a single line of text.

From [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Text.html).