# s:Label vs mx:Text?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I refer [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7103172/842112) 
Now I want to know What is the difference and Advantages Of `s:Label` over `mx:Text` in Flex 4
When These are most suitable?
**EDIT**
 Why I asked is in that specified "Use the Label control if you need only a single line of text." But `s:Label` supports Multiline.

Comment: A lot of people didn't like the one line restriction on mx:Label, so when Adobe made the new spark controls, they didn't restrict it.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship So for `s:Label`, no meaning for the Line "Use the Label control if you need only a single line of text." in the link [http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Text.html] :)

Comment: No. That comment predates the spark component and is ment to differentiate among the different controls MX had for dealing with text.

Answer (score 1):

`s:Label` is a Spark component, while `mx:Text` is a standard Flex component. You should try to use only one component system in your application, apart from that it doesn’t really matter although the Spark components are a bit more comfortable.

Regarding `:Label` vs `:Text` the same answer of that [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7103199/216074) still applies.

Comment: As you said " You should try to use only one component system in your application" But most of the components like `mx:AdvancedDatagrid` are standard Flex components. So we can Use same with Spark components Right?